# How to reuse Vagrant parameter in Chef

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I'm struggling to understand how to pass current vagrant configuration to chef.

For example during Vagrant provisioning I have this configuration:

```
config.vm.provider :aws do |aws, override|
   override.ssh.username = "ubuntu"
   ...
end

...

config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
  chef.json = {
      username: "ubuntu"
  }
  ...
end
```

Now how can I reuse the ssh `username` in **chef-solo** provisioning?
I would like be able to write something like this:

```
config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
  chef.json = {
      username: config.ssh.username
  }
end
```

Any help highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solutions seems very valid to me:

```
username = "ubuntu"

config.vm.provider :aws do |aws, override|
   override.ssh.username = "#{username}"
   ...
end

...

config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
  chef.json = {
      username: "#{username}"
  }
  ...
end
```

(thanks to Alvaro Miranda Aguilera how suggested this piece of code in [Vagrant forum](https://groups.google.com/d/msgid/vagrant-up/CAHqq0ezkzHKGLMBLaYALVtJ2GGi%2BMgR2iiocgKNF34WSenXEXQ%40mail.gmail.com?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer))